# How to run unix / shell commands with wildcards using Java?

Tags: java

I want to run some `unix/shell` commands in `Java` and process the output. I used `getRuntime.exec()`, but it is not giving correct output for some commands like `ls directory_path/*.tar.gz` . For that command my program is not giving any output but it is giving error saying `No such file or directory`. But the same command is giving correct output on command prompt.

Is there any other way to execute commands which include wildcards in  Java?

Comment: double check your path, also your current directory which you are on. 'No such file or directory' means it is executing the command correctly but the path is not what you thought what it is.

Comment: Do you just want to list files? You could do that with java code instead of running "native" tools that are system dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***Is there any other way to execute commands which include wildcards in  Java?***

Yes there is.

You have three potential problems in your code:

1. Assuming you want to see the output of the external command you need to take care of the output it produces, and print it yourself.

   Follow the example I've provided over here:

   - [How to make a java program to print both out.println() and err.println() statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754841/how-to-make-a-java-program-to-print-both-out-println-and-err-println-)
2. The shell expansion of `*` doesn't work if you naively go through `Runtime.exec`.You have to go through `/bin/bash` explicitly.
3. If you try to list the content of `directory_path/*.tar.gz` you should know that (if you're not starting with a `/`) `directory_path` will be resolved relative to the *current working directory*. Try at first to give the absolute path to make sure it works, and then try to figure out why it can't find the relative path.

Here's a complete example that should work:

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c",
                                  "ls /.../directory_path/*.tar.gz").start();

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
int ch;
while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1)
    System.out.print((char) ch);
reader.close();
```

Comment: thanks am getting correct output with this. so will it work for another commands also?

Comment: Yes, it will work for all kinds of commands. (But don't go through `/bin/bash` unless you really need support for wildcards.) Make sure you upvote all answers that are helpful, and [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Is there a non-OS-specific way of using wildcards from Java? `bash` might not exist on Windows.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka, what do you mean? Whatever external program you're running, it will be OS specific. If the external program is `ls` or `dir`, I would suggest you loop over the files in Java, and use regexps to filter out the interesting ones.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you specified a relative path to the directory and your application is running in a working directory. The path you specified is relative to that working directory.

To find out what the absolute path is, you can check out the working directory.

```
System.out.println("Working directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: You should know that this means that you have a folder in the root of your hdd, called "actual", assuming you are on a Unix-based OS.

Comment: yes. that is existed path only. the same command is working on command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

"ls directory_path/*.tar.gz" works relative to CURRENT directory.