# Linux terminal command in Java does not work

Tags: java, linux, bash

I'm trying to execute a linux command in my java code. It needs to change permissions for some directory.

Here is my attempt:

```
String  Cmd = "echo myPassword | sudo -S chmod 777 -R /home/somePath";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec(Cmd);
```

The command held in `String Cmd` is working perfectly when I used it in terminal. But when I use it in my code nothing happens. There is no error or warning feedback that helps me to understand my mistake. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java will not magically select `bash` as your executable. You probably want to do something like

```
"bash -c <your command>"
```

See this question:

- [How to run unix / shell commands with wildcards using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790240/how-to-run-unix-shell-commands-with-wildcards-using-java)

(Also the `|` is a bash-thing. Java won't magically create pipes between processes.)

Comment: Maybe you should mention that the `|` thing is part of the bash language and therefore it needs to be interpreted by bash (or similar shell).

Comment: Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo myPassword | sudo -S chmod 777 -R /home/somePath").start();