# Running a git command with wildcard works in bash but not through Process

Tags: git, scala, process, wildcard

I want to run `git check-ignore` using `sys.process.Process`. This works in the shell (bash):

```
$ cd /home/me/Documents/Foo
$ git check-ignore *
target
```

There is a directory `/home/me/Documents/Foo/target` that is being ignored through `/home/me/Documents/Foo/.gitignore`.

The same doesn't work when I run this through `sys.process`:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val workingDir = new java.io.File("/home/me/Documents/Foo")
Process(Seq("git", "check-ignore", "*"), workingDir).!
```

It gives return code 1, meaning that no file matched. If I specify the particular name, it works:

```
Process(Seq("git", "check-ignore", "target"), workingDir).!
```

This prints `target` and returns code zero.

So why doesn't the wildcard `*` work here, and how do I make it work (given that I want to list all ignored files and I have no prior knowledge what those files would be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is same as [How to run unix / shell commands with wildcards using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790240/how-to-run-unix-shell-commands-with-wildcards-using-java), You can implement it in **Scala** too, maybe like:

```
Process(Seq("bash", "-c", "git check-ignore *"), workingDir).!
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `*` is a wildcard expanded by bash and not directly support by `git check-ignored`. The way around is instead to list the children of the working directory, and pass them one by one as arguments to git.

Comment: Seth asked about ammonite-ops. Do they provide it? This is so basic, we can't go on forever asking why can't I have a `bash"cmd arg"` interpolator.