# Any way to release child process streams in java?

Tags: java, process, inputstream, outputstream

The javadoc of [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) says:

> The created subprocess does not have its own terminal or console. All its standard io (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be redirected to the parent process through three streams  (getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), getErrorStream()).

What is something I'd like to avoid and let the child do it's own stuff with its std streams. Is there any way to avoid the overtake of the streams?

Comment: What do you mean by *let the child do it's own stuff with its std streams*?

Comment: The current case is that I'm starting an OSGi application with a launcher that ensures the adequate conditions for the app. The OSGi process would do some logging to the stdout, but this way the log does not get printed. OK, this may be stupid, but somehow if I run the app with the launcher, other things get wrong... I had a python launcher earlier which was fine and haven't took the streams so as a first guess I blame the stream capture.

Comment: So you want the output of the external process to be printed on stdout?

Comment: Could say that. But ultimately I want to fix the rest of the errors. It seems that the osgi app starts blocking somewhere when it runs with its streams redirected, but I have to investigate it more.

Comment: I've written some other answers that may be of help then: [answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754841/how-to-make-a-java-program-to-print-both-out-println-and-err-println-stateme), [answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591215/run-external-program-concurrently) and [answer 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754841/how-to-make-a-java-program-to-print-both-out-println-and-err-println-stateme)

Comment: @aioobe: thanks I'll take a look at them later.

Comment: @aioobe: I've just tried one. And it works! Thanks. The real problem was, that the java.util.Logger of the child process threw uncaught exceptions when the parent wasn't reading the output streams. This was really unexpected, since the neither `console` nor `consoleLog` was specified for the OSGi framework. Maybe the logger config overrode this...