# Java class return windows command line information

Tags: java, command-line

I am able to execute commands from the commandline with the code below. If a pass a working command to the code it processes and give me a return value. What I need is to get the response from the command line when it does not process correctly. So if I pass a copy command to the prompt and it executes I get a value. If I pass a copy command to the prompt and it fails I get no value. Here is my code

```
public String CommandLineExecuteReturn(String loc)
 {
    String returnValue = "";
    String outValue = null;
    try 
     {   
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c "+ loc);   
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(   
                           new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));   
       String line = null;   
       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {   
          ; 
           returnValue = line;
        }   
      } 
    catch (IOException e) 
      {   
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String stacktrace = sw.toString();
        returnValue = stacktrace;   
      }   

    return returnValue ;
 }
```

Comment: I am really struggling to understand your question.Sorry can you please reframe it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to redirect the error stream (`p.getErrorStream()`) - note that reading from both streams will require two threads.

Alternatively and more easily, you could use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29) and call its `redirectErrorStream(true)` method.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754841/how-to-make-a-java-program-to-print-both-out-println-and-err-println-stateme).