# bat file does not execute within Java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have written some code for executing `.bat` file. which contains some
commands like setting java `classpath,etc`..And finally there is one command
which runs a Java class file.The H`elloWorld class` converts some xml file and generating a new xml file in some folder. When I double click .bat file, it executes fine,
but when I try to run I am not getting any output as I was getting through
double click the `.bat` file.  How to make a batch execute and probably it would be nice
if I could see the results through Java console.

Following is MyJava code to execute the .bat file

```
public void run2() {
        try {
            String []commands = {"cmd.exe","/C","C:/MyWork/Java/classes/run.bat"} ;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And below the some commands which has been set to .bat file

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:/MyWork/Java
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:/MyWork/Java/classes
java -cp test.jar;test2.jar test.HelloWorld
```

Tried with `"/C"` commad as well. It does not execute. Actually it does not give effect of double click the `.bat` file. Is there any other way that I can try with?

I can see the contents inside the `.bat` file through Eclipse console. But it does not give the desired output. Desired output means when I double click `.bat` file, it executes well. But through `java`  call, I can see the contents only .

Comment: How do you start your program? When running it using java.exe, do you see some output from the bat-file when it is executed.

Comment: I get some time FileNotFoundException when I double click .bat file if the particular .xml file does not found. With the same scenario when I run through java file, I dont get any exception or anything. I dont know whether classname specified inside the .bat file run successfully or not.

Comment: Is there any console-output from your above code?? Try adding some `System.out.println`s to make sure alle statements are executed

Comment: I have added one "System.out.println("Done!!!");" But it does not get executed and also the while loop is not getting exited. The program never terminates. But if I remove the while loop, it gets terminated with the "Done!!!" message inthe console.

Comment: @EnglishLearner You must first try your *.bat from the **comand line**. If that works, run your Java program from the command line. No clicky, clacky in some IDE or windows explorer, you're wasting your time.

Comment: @Ingo It works through command line. If the bat has to be executed through java program, and if it does not work, we need to identify the problem right? Since I have not done this previously, I need to find out the whats wrong with my code in order not to execute the code. thats why I put in this forum.

Comment: Sure, @EnglishLearner, but I keep reading "in eclipse, it is thus, and when I double-click that". This is all irrelevant. Just run your program from the command line. Note also, that you should read and replicate the error output, otherwise you cannot see the errors that happen.

Comment: Also, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754841/how-to-make-a-java-program-to-print-both-out-println-and-err-println-stateme/3754881#3754881

Comment: @EnglishLearner: Have you already tried Desktop.getDesktop().open(batchfile); instead? (May not work on all platforms.) Also, in case part of your problem is to get a console application to work via double-click, I just made a class that makes that possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32547250/3500521

Answer (score 2):

When using cmd.exe use `/C`-Parameter to pass command:

```
String []commands = {"cmd.exe","/C","C:/MyWork/Java/classes/run.bat"} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true), the Windows CMD needs the `/c` argument, to execute commands like this. try this:

```
String []commands = {"cmd.exe","/c","C:/MyWork/Java/classes/run.bat"} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses **\ backslash** for Windows and MS-DOS path delimiter. Forward slash / is accepted by Java in the `java.io` package and translated to be a path delimiter, but will not be directly acceptable to Windows or accepted by the `cmd.exe` shell.

You may also need to specify either the *working directory* for the batch file to be executed in, or possibly a *full path* to the `cmd.exe` command interpreter.

See:  `Runtime.exec (String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)`

```
String[] commands = {"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", 
    "C:\\MyWork\\Java\\classes\\run.bat"};
File workDir = new File( "C:/MyWork");
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( commands, null, workDir);
```

To verify if the batch file is run at all, add a `pause` command to the batch file. That will keep the window open so you can verify if the batch file is launched at all, and debug this stage-by-stage.

Comment: I had added pause (pause > nul)command to the .bat file. But it does not popup the .cmd. I suspect commands which I have written does not execute. Btw how to specify workding directory?"C:/MyWork/Java/classes/run.bat" Is this not a workding directory? can you please explain?

Comment: See my edit, forward-slashes are not Windows/MS-DOS path syntax and I think those may be the biggest problem. @EnglishLearner

Comment: I can see the contents inside the .bat file through Eclipse console. But it does not give the desired output. Desired output means when I double click .bat file, it executes well. But through java when I call, I can see the contents only not.

Comment: 1.) My version of cmd.exe (Windows 7) does accept forward-slashes 2.) You have to escape backslashes in java String-literals (`"\\"`)

Comment: Backslash needs to be escaped, \\ -- good point @piet.t -- but I'm running Win 7,  just tested it & it fails to understand a forward-slash in the `cmd /c path\batchfile` invocation.

Comment: I use windows xp.but when we deploy the application any other windows version, it would be a problem isnt it?

Comment: **Cmd.exe command-line syntax needs proper backslash syntax on any version of Windows, past or future.** This is never going to change, as compatibility must be preserved with existing commands & scripts.

Comment: See:  http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23123-when-did-windows-start-accepting-forward-slash-path-separator

Comment: @EnglishLearner -- Solved your problem. `cmd /c Tom/test.bat` doesn't work at the command-prompt (I tried it), but with backslash it does & ran a sample batch-file. As I said in my answer, you have to use backslash for paths in MS-DOS/Windows shell commands.

Comment: Strange, `String []commands = {"cmd.exe","/C","E:/test.bat"}` did work for me without problems....

Comment: Use of forward-slash is known to be unreliable in `cmd.exe` and Windows/DOS command shells, since forward slash is parsed as "option separator". Backslash is specified to be the correct path-delimiter on Windows, so use that. See link provided in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You do not read the error output of your batch file, therefore, you'll never see any error messages printed from there or from CMD.EXE itself. In addition, the sub-program may stall and just wait for you to read the error stream.

Please see related discussions here: [How to make a java program to print both out.println() and err.println() statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754841/how-to-make-a-java-program-to-print-both-out-println-and-err-println-stateme/3754881#3754881)