# Java Process: read stdout and stderr of a subprocess in a single thread

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

Suppose I have started a subprocess in Java, that may write to stdout and stderr:

```
Process subprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(…);
```

I want to read all its stdout and stderr; or just ignore them.

1. If I do like this:

   ```
   readAllFrom(subprocess.getInputStream()); //stdout is getInputStream, weird!
   readAllFrom(subprocess.getErrorStream()); //stderr
   ```

   … it'll stuck, if subprocess first tries to output data to stderr and thus blocks at that point.

   And if I do something like this:

   ```
   while (…) {
       readLineFrom(subprocess.getInputStream());
       readLineFrom(subprocess.getErrorStream());
   }
   ```

   … the risk, actually, seems to be the same.
2. If I do like this:

   ```
   while (…) {
       nonblockingReadFrom(subprocess.getInputStream());
       nonblockingReadFrom(subprocess.getOutputStream());
   }
   ```

   where `nonblockingReadFrom` can be something like:

   ```
   … nonblockingReadFrom(InputStream stream) {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[…];
       stream.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(stream.available(), buffer.length));
       …
   }
   ```

   … it will make useless 100%-CPU-loads, if subprocess outputs data with some pauses.
3. Of course, I can create separate thread. Something like here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/1421194), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4274535/1421194)). But my question is about doing all in the same thread. Probably, something like Java interface to [select system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) is needed for that.

So, the question is: **Is it possible to handle correctly stdout and stderr of a `java.lang.Process`-typed subprocess in Java without using additional threads or temporary files?**

Comment: Have you seen this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki ?

Comment: @GhostCat, seems to be unrelated. Accepted answer uses stream gobblers, which is multi-threaded solution. Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer just redirects stdout and stderr of subprocess to stdout and stderr of main process accordingly, which isn't my goal.

Comment: Is redirecting stderr into stdout an option?  If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754841) may help.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program. It may be helpful for your purposes.

Comment: @LukeWoodward, of course no.

Comment: @eg04lt3r, the accepted answer from your link, per my opinion, demonstrates wrong approach (it's actually aproach #1 from my question). The program, AFAIK, will block if a subprocess first tries to output to stderr, and only then to stdout. If I'm wrong, please, tell me why.

Comment: 1) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thank for a good link, I actually read it before posting my question (it doesn't address my question, it proposes stream gobblers, which are actually multi-threaded solution). As for MCVE and SSCCE, I can't provide any example, as I don't know how to solve my theoretical question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, actually, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) don't apply here, because I'm no discussing *problem caused by my code* or *problem with some code* at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't just create a `SelectableChannel` from the `InputStream` returned by a `Process`, this is a Java api limitation AFAICT.

Comment: *"I think you can just wait for process termination and then inspect both streams."* <— Won't subprocess block, if it tries to output a lot of data, and I'm not reading the streams?

Comment: Yes, it will block if you don't consume the streams (you can try it yourself by running a `cat /dev/urandom` subprocess). That's why you should use a thread if the subprocess is going to produce a considerable amount of output and you don't want to block the parent while reading.

Comment: then, please, remove second part of your answer (which IMO confuses readers), so that I can't accept it (if I understood it correctly, the first part means ***No, as of Java 8 it's currently impossible.***).

Comment: While this answer indicates that turning stdin and stdout into Selectable channels is impossible, I still wonder if there is any *other* way in Java to achieve the same goal: reacting to messages in stdin and stdout simultaneously.